# Mysql data dictionary hold CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on the queries like(select, update, delete and insert) if yes then how to access it

Tags: mysql, dictionary

Can Mysql **data dictionary** hold CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on all the queries like (select, update, delete and insert) if yes then how to access it

Comment: What is `MySQL data dictionary`?

Comment: The term is not often used, but it refers (if i'm not mistaken) to metadata. So, for example the data that is stored in the information_schema database.
Still, i don't really understand what it is exactly that the TS wants.

Comment: yes data dictionary means meta data. can we see the time for each event in the meta data. plz explain

Comment: Are you asking how to log queries?

Answer (score 0):

By default, MySQL will not use computer resources (CPU, memory and disk) and slow down general operation in order to keep a record of all the queries ran on the server. I believe this is true for most DBMS.

The feature is called [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html) and can be enabled if needed:

> By default, the general query log is disabled. To specify the initial
>   general query log state explicitly, use `--general_log[={0|1}]`. With no
>   argument or an argument of 1, `--general_log` enables the log. With an
>   argument of 0, this option disables the log. To specify a log file
>   name, use `--general_log_file=file_name`. To specify the log
>   destination, use `--log-output`